# Installing PowerShell Module due to Write-S3Object not found

Tags: powershell

Im trying to use Write-S3Object on a Windows server but it errors out that it isn’t found.
Haivng run Get-Module -ListAvailable I can see the machine has AWS.Tools installed on it and I believe I need to install AWSPowerShell.NetCore so that I can use the command Write-S3Object

If I install AWSPowerShell.NetCore does it get installed alongside AWS.Tools?
Or does AWSPowerShell.NetCore overwrite AWS.Tools?

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using (`"$($PSVersionTable['PSVersion'])"`)? Is `Write-S3Object` available if you do `Import-Module AWS.Tools.S3` first? FWIW the two modules should be able to live side-by-side, installing 1 won't overwrite the other.

Comment: Version is 5.1.14393.5582    So the Import-Module AWS.Tools.S3 should basically contain all commands related to S3 right?

Comment: `Import-Module AWS.Tools.S3` will import all the commands in that sub-module, yes - you should be able to list them all with `Get-Command -Module AWS.Tools.S3` afterwards